# C# How to retrieve data from 2 different length Array List?

Tags: c#

I have 2 array list with different length and I wish to retrieve the data and arrange them in desired sequence. My coding is as follow:

```
        ArrayList Alist = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList Blist = new ArrayList();

        Alist.Add(10);
        Alist.Add(20);
        Alist.Add(30);

        Blist.Add("Y");
        Blist.Add("Z");
        string Result = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < Alist.Count; i++)
        {
            Result += Alist[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < Blist.Count; j++)
            {
                Result += Blist[j];
                break;
            }
         Console.WriteLine(Result);
         Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

My desired output should be

> 10Y20Z30

, but this program is giving output

> 10Y20Y30Y

At the same time, an unreachable code is detected, which is `int j`
Hope anyone could correct me
Thanks.

Comment: You should use `List<T>`.  And, you should probably write a class.

Comment: 1. What is the purpose of this, why even write this code? Homework problem maybe? 2. Use a generic list or array, not ArrayList. This will give you type safety.

Comment: @Igor Yes, this is a homework, i have submitted a version with using array and my tutor is requesting me to use array list, and this make me in trouble

Comment: Is the length of `Alist` always greater than the length of `Blist`? What if it's the other way around?

Comment: To reiterate what others are saying, `ArrayList` is very outdated at this point. Unless your tutor has some underlying point I can't imagine, I'd just use a `List<T>`. Better in every way.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program with a debugger to see what's really happening?

Comment: Isn't your output "10YZ20YZ30YZ"?

Comment: @ekad yes, Alist always greater than Blist

Comment: The int j (j++) is unreachable because you have a break statement which basically stops the loop on the first run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //....
 var j = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < Alist.Count; i++)
 {
       Result += Alist[i];
       if (j < Blist.Count)
            Result += Blist[j++];
  }
  while (j < Blist.Count) //in case B length> A length
     Result += Blist[j++];

  Console.WriteLine(Result);
  Console.ReadLine();
  //....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same `for` loop and just use the size of the smaller as a termination condition, i.e. calculate the `min` of the two sizes.

```
    // define objects
    ArrayList Alist = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList Blist = new ArrayList();

    // add elements
    Alist.Add(10);
    Alist.Add(20);
    Alist.Add(30);

    Blist.Add("Y");
    Blist.Add("Z");

    // 
    string Result = string.Empty;

    // accumulate result as: ABABABA with size = 2 * (size of smaller)
    int min = Math.Min(Alist.Count, Blist.Count);

    var j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++)
    {
        Result += Alist[i];
        Result += Blist[i];
        j = i;
    }

    // as A always > B then (as OP said),
    // increment and concatenate the next element of array list A
    ++j;
    Result += Alist[j];

    // display result
    Console.WriteLine(Result);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

> 10Y20Z30

Comment: the last "30" will be missing. `j` is not declared.

Comment: This output of this code is `10Y20Z` instead of `10Y20Z30`, see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mdX70H). You're missing the third element of `Alist`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that for *every* element in `Alist` you start a new loop over `Blist`, but break that loop immediatly after the first element. That explains your result and the "unreachable code" warning.

To achieve your desired result you can do the following:

```
Result = string.Join(string.Empty, Alist.OfType<int>()
              .Select(
               (i, index) => i.ToString() + (index < Blist.Count ? Blist[index].ToString() : string.Empty)));
```

This combines all the elements from `Alist` with the elements in `Blist´ at the same index.

If there are more elements in `Blist` you can add them at the end with:

```
Result += string.Join(string.Empty, Blist.OfType<string>().Skip(Alist.Count));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just need one loop, although it's a little risky if you have differently sized arrays. Right now you're looping through the entire Blist for every Alist value, which I don't think is what you want. A very naive way of approaching the problem would be something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Alist.Count; i++) {
    Result+= Alist[i];
    Result+= Blist[i];
}
```

However you're going to run into problems, A has 3 elements while B only has 2. B[2] is going to return a ArgumentOutOfRangeException. So let's make sure you're not going to run into that problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Alist.Count; i++) {
    Result+= Alist[i];
    if(i < Blist.Count) {
        Result+= Blist[i];
    }
}
```

This should properly combine the lists. If you're not sure which list is larger, you can do a little logic before the loop to make sure it'll properly combine.

```
ArrayList longerList = (Alist.Count >= Blist.Count) ? Alist : Blist;
ArrayList shorterList = (Alist.Count >= Blist.Count) ? Blist : Alist;

for (int i = 0; i < longerList.Count; i++) {
    Result += longerList[i];
    if (i < shorterList.Count) {
        Result += shorterList[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //...
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var max = Math.Max(Alist.Count, Blist.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        {
            if (Alist.Count > i)
                strBuilder.Append(Alist[i]);

            if (Blist.Count > i)
                strBuilder.Append(Blist[i]);
        }

        var result = strBuilder.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```